# Custom Class in Swift using SKSpritenodes/Collision Detection

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, subclass, collision, skspritenode

I am currently working on a game where enemies get spawned from the left of the screen and move right.  I want to give these enemies their own attributes (health, strength, etc).  So I am working on creating a Basic_fighter class.  I also have a user sniper scope that the user uses to hit the enemies.  The problem I have is how to access the enemies attributes in the DidBeginContact Function since the function only returns two nodes, and not the class information.  I will put my code below

**Basic_Fighter_Class**

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class Basic_Fighter  {

var health = Int()
var type = SKSpriteNode()

init(sk:SKSpriteNode){

    self.type = sk
    self.health = 3

}  
}
```

---

```
func spawn_enemies(){

    let enemynode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Shooter")
    enemynode.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 40)
    enemynode.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height / 2)
    enemynode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: enemynode.size)
    enemynode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    enemynode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.enemy
    enemynode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.bullet

    let enemy = Basic_Fighter(sk: enemynode)
    addChild(enemynode)
}
```

I am able to detect the contact made between the user scope and the enemy in the DidBeginContact function, but I do not know how to access the information of the enemy, such as its health.

Comment: just access the node feature of the body in the didbegincontact,  this is available on multiple tutorials,  then you just cast it to the class that it belongs to

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can access it with enemynode.health, I'm not sure though.